# « ne + infinitif + pas » au lieu de « ne pas + infinitif »

Tags: grammaire, négation, ordre-des-mots, infinitif

Les Misérables, p. 875 :

> Une bête à bon Dieu écrasée, une plume tombée d'un nid, une branche d'aubépine cassée, les apitoyait, et leur extase, doucement noyée de mélancolie, semblait **ne demander pas** mieux que de pleurer.

Je me demande pourquoi l'auteur a écrit « ne demander pas » au lieu de « ne pas demander », l'ordre usuellement trouvé dans la littérature. Sauf que c'est un vieux livre, je ne peux trouver aucune raison.

Comment: Ça ne me choque pas, mais c'est surtout à cause de ce qui suit, _pas mieux_ semblant fortement lié. Pour info, un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ne+pas+demander+mieux%2Cne+demander+pas+mieux&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cne%20pas%20demander%20mieux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cne%20demander%20pas%20mieux%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cne%20pas%20demander%20mieux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cne%20demander%20pas%20mieux%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Je ne fais pas une réponse car je ne connais pas la règle, mais ce n'est pas choquant, et mon ressenti c'est que la construction est autorisée car il y a `mieux` derrière. Ce n'est pas qu'il "ne demande pas", c'est qu'il "ne demande pas mieux". Cela fonctionnerait aussi avec `pas autant`, `pas autre chose`, et d'autres. La construction plus habituelle reste autorisée dans tous ces cas. La construction que tu cites me semble plus littéraire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comme je comprend cette inversion elle sert à mettre la négation sur l'adverbe et le mot « ne » ne serait qu'un explétif ; c'est un cas de négation non lié au verbe, cet aspect de la négation étant traité dans *Le Bon Usage* bien que ce cas particulier semble manquer.

- […] leur extase, doucement noyée de mélancolie, semblait  demander  de pleurer, rien de mieux.

Si l'on avait la construction normale,

- […] leur extase, doucement noyée de mélancolie, semblait ne pas demander  mieux que de pleurer. »,

on aurait l'impression qu'aucune demande n'est faite. Si aucune demande n'est faite il importe peu de mesurer une demande, de l'évaluer à une demande d'une sorte ou d'une autre. Ce qui compte ici c'est qu'une demande est faite, que l'on sent qu'elle est faite et elle n'a pas plus de grandeur, ou d'esprit, ou quoi que soit les termes pour la caractériser, que celle de pleurer.